# Count occurrences of number from specific column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do the equivalent of a COUNTIF() function in excel. I am stuck at how to tell the .count() function to read from a specific column in excel.

I have

```
df = pd.read_csv('testdata.csv')    
df.count('1')
```

but this does not work, and even if it did it is not specific enough. 
I am thinking I may have to use read_csv to read specific columns individually.

Example:

```
Column name
4
4
3
2
4
1
```

the function would output that there is one '1' and I could run it again and find out that there are three '4' answers. etc.

I got it to work! Thank you

I used:

```
print (df.col.value_counts().loc['x']
```

Comment: Probably looking for `value_counts`.  Try `df.col.value_counts().loc[1]`

Comment: I think that is the one im looking for but I got an error 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col'.

Comment: You have to replace it with the name of the colum you want to count

Comment: `col` is the column name in your csv file

Comment: `df.eq('1').sum()`

Comment: alright now im getting 'function' object has no attribute 'value_counts'. Is this because of it being a series method? Or something like that?

Comment: Please post an example (head) of your data and the expected output you would see if your code was successful.

Comment: I have added it.

Comment: @JacobClark In SO you must not add [SOLVED] to your title, you must mark the answer as correct, if none of the answers help you then we invite you to publish your own answer.

Comment: Oh ok, one of the comments helped so I will just leave my edit.

Comment: @JacobClark No, the comments are volatile, they can be deleted and your question will not be useful, post a answer and mark it as correct or invite the person who helped you to do it, otherwise use `@` to notify another user of a message .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a simple 'countif' recipe you could try:

```
import pandas as pd

def countif(rng, criteria):
    return rng.eq(criteria).sum()
```

#### Example use

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': [4,4,3,2,4,1],
                   'column2': [1,2,3,4,5,6]})
countif(df['column1'], 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, why not try something like this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pandas.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0, 100, size=100), columns=["col1"])

counters = {}
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.iloc[i]["col1"] in counters:
        counters[df.iloc[i]["col1"]] += 1
    else:
        counters[df.iloc[i]["col1"]] = 1

print(counters)
plt.bar(counters.keys(), counters.values())
plt.show()
```